# Problem while trying to create a react-native app while using android studio

Tags: react-native, mobile, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Have been bumping into an error while trying to create a react app using android studio. Tried to solve it but couldn't.
I have even tried to uninstall and reinstall android studio but i still get the same error

I have been trying to create a react project using android studio but have been running into this error:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'cont_project'.

> Could not determine the dependencies of null.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
> > Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:.
> Required by:
> project :
> > Could not resolve com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin.
> Required by:
> project :
> > No matching variant of project :gradle-plugin was found. The consumer was configured to find a library for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally, as well as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '8.0.1' but:
> - Variant 'apiElements' capability com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin:unspecified declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
> - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during compile-time, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8
> - Other compatible attribute:
> - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0.1')
> - Variant 'mainSourceElements' capability com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin:unspecified declares a component, and its dependencies declared externally:
> - Incompatible because this component declares a component of category 'verification' and the consumer needed a library
> - Other compatible attributes:
> - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
> - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
> - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0.1')
> - Doesn't say anything about its usage (required runtime)
> - Variant 'runtimeElements' capability com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin:unspecified declares a library for use during runtime, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
> - Incompatible because this component declares a component, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component, compatible with Java 8
> - Other compatible attribute:
> - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0.1')
> - Variant 'testResultsElementsForTest' capability com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin:unspecified:
> - Incompatible because this component declares a component of category 'verification' and the consumer needed a library
> - Other compatible attributes:
> - Doesn't say anything about how its dependencies are found (required its dependencies declared externally)
> - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility withabout its usage (required runtime)

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 39s
error Failed to install the app.

Anyone know the cause and how i can fix it

Comment: Why create the project in Android Studio instead of the recommended way with React Native CLI?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your question. It seems like you are not familiar with the standards of Stack Overflow regarding questions. Please read following article: [How To: Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Afterwards adjust your question accordingly by using the [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77068047/edit) option.

Answer (score 0):

I runned the app from Visual studio Code terminal and not from Android Studio

I faced this same issue after creating new React Native Project and after that I have set the Java JDK path 11 version ie: (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11) and name given as JAVA_HOME in environment variables windows system and restarted the system.

After that it is working till android emulator sdk version 33 and not working from sdk version 34 onwards, So please try this solution ,It may help you